# function and meaning of "take" in "Take your weaknesses and . . ."

Tags: word-meaning

What does "take" mean in the following?

> Take your weaknesses and translate them into positives.

How does the above differ from "Translate your weaknesses into positives"?
What's the function of "take"?

Answer (score 2):

It means to *consider* your weaknesses, maybe one by one, instead of ignoring them. There are many senses of *take* in dictionaries; this one may be fairly close to the sense here:

[Collins Dictionary *take*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take) 
24.
You use *take* when you are discussing or explaining a particular question, in order to introduce an example or to say how the question is being considered.

*There's confusion and resentment. **Take** this office, for example.*
*You can attack this problem from many angles, but let's **take** one thing at a time.*
***Taken** in isolation these statements can be dangerous fallacies.*
Synonyms: **consider, study, think about, examine**

[dictionary definition edited for brevity and emphasis]

The sentence "Translate your weaknesses into positives." has the same meaning, in effect, but not the same idiomatic feel.